# how to delete and remove a Grid tile with its space from a Grid with angular

Tags: angular, list, bootstrap-4, grid, responsive

I am trying to create a page that contains a list of different articles, I have one component and iterate over the list of articles 
my question is

1. when I close/delete one article I need it to disappear from the page, and the other element take its place, which I cannot do because I am using a GRID, and the Grid tile is already defined 
   . is there amy solutions or other ways to do this

[stackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-grid-flnlup)

```
<mat-grid-list [cols]="breakpoint" rowHeight="4:2"  
              (window:resize)="onResize($event)">
  <mat-grid-tile id="obj"
     *ngFor="let item of items"           
      [style.background]="'lightblue'">
      <div >
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <div>some sort of text in between</div>
        <button mat-raised-button class="mi-button" 
        (click)="delete()">Delete</button>
      </div>
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Compenent

```
    delete(){
    document.getElementById("obj").style.display = 'none'
     }
```

Comment: The stackblitz doesn't demonstrate the problem? And you'll need to post some the relevant code too instead of just a link.

Comment: I just correct it

Comment: Thanks, that's a good demo now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular, you let the model dictate what the HTML should be, rather than trying to remove elements from the DOM manually.

You are currently building your grid from your model - GOOD

You are trying to delete items from your grid directly via the DOM - BAD

Instead, you need to indicate which item should be removed when you call the delete function. I am going to pass the original item into the delete function so that you can find its array and delete it from the array. When the array is modified, Angular will rebuild the HTML.

component.html

```html
<mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let item of items">
  <h2>Title {{item.name}}</h2>  
  <button (click)="delete(item)">Delete</button>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

component.ts

```js
delete(item) {
  const index = this.items.indexOf(item);
  this.items.splice(index, 1);
}
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-grid-znlou6